# Excel array formula to copy value based on matching criteria within group

Tags: excel

[image: sample data]

I have the above data populated until column D (i.e. Top Priority column). I am looking for a formula to copy values in column E (top priority acc no. in column E is the desired result shown in the image).

i.e. Match Top Priority(D) to Priority(C) column , where the match is true copy the corresponding-same row for column account number value in the column E. This has to be applied in the groupings of all the Location values, in column A.

I think it would be some sought of index match  array function but I'm not able to build the formula if someone can helps please. Thanks

Comment: Hi Naresh, Thank you very much for your reply. But it doesn't work fully. For example according to the above data in row number 8, it is copying "700 800" however it should copy "750 091", since 2 is the top priority value , and the corresponding account no. for priority column is 2 "750 091" within Group A_02.

Comment: No.. E2 `=IF(D2=C2,B2,INDEX($B$2:B2,MATCH(A2,$A$2:A2,0),1))` and copy down was giving the exact result as shown in your table. There was another reason for deleting the comment. Thought, what if the First Priority for location is not Top Priority. For example, In Case of A_03 if your top priority is 9 then that formula will not work. If the first priority (Col C) for every location is always the top priority (Col D) then that formula will work for all locations

Comment: Also, there is an assumption for the formula in the comment above, that the data is sorted on Location

Comment: Not sure how my comment got deleted. Anyways. Thanks Naresh, you got it absolutely right. I basically want it that way only, i.e. if my top priority is 9 then it should be pick up the corresponding account value irrespective of the order the priority column is in. so based on priority column 9 corresponds to 200 500 , and since 9 is my top pririty that is the value i need printed in column E

Comment: Posting an answer. If any answer is suitable upvote/ accept it with a tick

Comment: Well actually it kind of still works, as my Top Priority column with have only "one" value of all the Priority values in a group. So if the priority values are  5 and 9 , top priority it will be either of it (5 in this example) and currently it is sorted on Priority so formula works. but if the raw data is not sorted , i.e. 9 before 5 and 9 becomes my top priority than i will have problem. Pls see if you can help in that case to be absolutely right, if not , not a problem, Thanks a lot still this does the job for now. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry i m new to stack overflow, i cant find an option to upvote now

Comment: I didn't get that 'sorting' question. even if the data is not sorted formula is still working fine, even if 9 is before 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array (Control + Shift + Enter) Formula in E2 and copy down

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(D2,(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,$C$2:$C$10)),0),1)`

[image]

Formula is fine even if the data in not sorted on Location. Make sure top priority is same on all rows for a given location. Say, if you change D7 to 4, then E7 will be 800 as the formula will look for the 4th priority for the A2 location.

Comment: Yep. thanks a lot Naresh It works. I still didnt get the option to upvote. :-(

Comment: Its up arrow besides the answer on left. You can accept the answer with a tick or wait for another better answer.